# Nil NSString method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` that is stored in Core Data. It is optional, which I believe in the sqlite db means it can be null. I have a convenience method I call 'isEmptyOrWhitespace' shown here:

```
- (BOOL)isEmptyOrWhiteSpace {
    return self == nil ||
    self.length == 0 ||
    [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0;
}
```

When my string from Core Data is nil, it doesn't seem to call this method, that is the breakpoints are never hit. This is particularly annoying because a code chunk like this:

```
if(![string isEmptyOrWhitespace]) {
    [string doSomething];
}
```

`doSomething` is being run if string is nil, obviously not my intent. Is there a way to get around this without checking if my string is nil before calling a method on it? Or is this a "feature" of Objective-C that methods aren't run on nil objects?

Comment: `self == nil` is nonsensical. The code would never run if that condition were true.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter I'm getting that now. I'll leave it up so no one else makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `string` is `nil`, then `[string isEmptyOrWhitespace]` does nothing, because sending messages to `nil` is a no-op.

**EDIT:** As @Jim pointed out, this answer is not correct. `[nil isEmptyOrWhitespace]` returns `0`, and that is the real reason that the `if ()` block is not executed if `string = nil`.

Comment: More precisely, it doesn't "do nothing", it returns `0`/`nil`, which is interpreted as `NO`.

Comment: If you fix this by inverting the logic of your convenience method, then you'll also want to check for equality to `[NSNull null]`.

Comment: @Jim: You are correct with respect to the return value, so my answer is in fact wrong. Is it OK if I correct my answer or do you want to post your own answer? In that case I will delete mine.

Comment: Go ahead and alter yours, you were right in principle and he could solve the problem from your answer, so you should get the credit.

Comment: @Jim: Testing for equality with `[NSNull null]` inside an `NSString` method doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jim: You want to test against `nil`. `[NSNull null]` and `nil` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter, you're right, I was thinking of when it's a standalone function or category method on `NSObject`.

Comment: @mipadi, no you want to test for both.  I obviously know they aren't the same thing, if I thought they were the same thing, why would I suggest testing for `[NSNull null]` when he's already testing for `nil`?

Comment: @Jim: Why would you check to see if it's `[NSNull null]`?

Comment: Because in practically every instance you are checking for `nil` and empty strings, it's because you want to ensure you have actual content.  `[NSNull null]` is an obvious omission you should account for when doing a check like this.

Answer (score -1):

Martin's answer is accurate. What you need is a convenience method on your core data entity class to verify the length of that string. If the string is nil, the length will be zero, and you can know if it's empty or nil.